# How to create a circular button in android with image in the background?

Tags: android, android-button

I want to create a circular button in android. This the xml I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">
<solid android:color="#9F2200"/>
<stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#fff" />
</shape>
```

Now when I put a button in the layout, I will have to set the above xml as the

```
android:background
```

attribute. But then how can I put an image within the circular button I have generated. How to accomplish this within the xml itself?

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton)?

Comment: Yes, but i want it to be a normal image button

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using FrameLayout

```
<FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:background="your selector" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/fbLogin"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="yourimage"
                android:gravity="center"/>
        </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

If I got it you can use an `ImageButton`, which lets you choose both a background with `android:background` and a drawable resource with `android:src`.

Answer (score 0):

Use an ImageButton and set your image with the src tag: `android:src="@drawable/your_image"`